# Normalise for a very small database?

Tags: normalization

I am designing a very small database (c. 250 rows). I have a number of datapoints for each record, which under normalization rules, ought to be in separate tables.

For instance:

1. Percentages of a number of different categories (which should add up to 100)
2. Multiple sources of data (for instance a record may come from up to 4 sources of data - the reference within these data sources should be recorded
3. Columns with very different units for instance I want to store residential units and Gross Floor area delivered (different units).

All these fields are optional, none are mandatory.

I am considering not normalizing in case 1, because I want a data integrity check that all the relevant columns in each database row add up to 100%.

For the other two cases, it seems that it is a lot of work to normalise for not a lot of gain. For 3, I would have to design 2 additional tables, one to store the data:

```
| ID(prim key) | project(FK)          | type(int) | value(float) |
|--------------|----------------------|-----------|--------------|
| 1            |  1                   | 1         | 200.3        |
```

and another to store the column metadata:

```
| ID(prim key) | typeID(FK)  | Description |
|--------------|-------------|-------------|
| 1            | 1           |    GFA(m2)  |
```

rather than just do this in the main table:

```
| RecordID(prim key) | GFA(m2) | Residential units | .... |
|--------------------|---------|-------------------|------|
| 1                  | 200     | 25                | .... |
```

With such small data, my main concern is updating things if the schema changes, but I can't think of a reason that will be harder with the de-normalised data.#

Can anyone give me a good reason to normalise for cases 2 and 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a small database with just a few rows, you might say that the design is whatever you can maintain and sustain. However, a few things to think about include:

1. Remember that the first implementation is not the future implementation.  Planning ahead just a little can save headaches in the future.
2. If the database should scale up in the future you might find yourself refactoring tables and code.
3. Since in `Table3` the columns are named `GFA(m2)`, `Residential units`, et cetera for whatever you are measuring you, you are committing to changing that table repeatedly as new measures are added.

By the way, I note that your `values(float)` of 200.3 becomes 200 in the final table. (Maybe just a typo.)  But be sure to keep the data types of the columns defined to fit the data you are storing.

And, yes, if I was delivering this to someone I would normalize it further.